# Changing the input record seperator to \n or \r when parsing lines

Tags: perl

I have a perl script that reads outputs (line by line) piped from another process, does a bit processing and spews out its results:

```
#!/bin/bash 
set -e
set -o pipefail

RUN.SH ${@} 2>&1 | perl -M"Term::ANSIColor" -wnl -e '
m/ERROR/i and print "\e[1;91m", "$_", "\e[0m" 
or print;'
```

And it works great, unless the output of process `RUN.SH` does not end with a new line (`\n`) and ends with `\r` instead! In this case this Perl parser does not print anything until the next `\n`. I need to change it such that it would use both `\n` and `\r` as input record separators.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Nitpick: you `use Term::ANSIColor` but you don't actually *use* Term::ANSIColor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four ways to read from a file:

- One character a time: `getc`
- One line at a time: `readline` with `$/ = $terminator;`
- One block at a time: `read` and `readline` with `$/ = \$length;`
- As data arrives: `sysread`

`getc` would work, but I'll use the more efficient `sysread`.

```
perl -we'
   sub make_iter {
      my ($fh) = @_;

      my $buf = "";
      my $eof = 0;

      return sub {
         return if $eof;

         while (1) {
            return $1 if $buf =~ s/^([^\r\n]*[\r\n])//;

            my $rv = sysread(STDIN, $buf, 64*1024, length($buf));
            if (!$rv) {
               $eof = 1;
               die $! if !defined($rv);
               return $buf if length($buf);
               return;
            }
         }
      };
   }

   binmode(STDIN);
   binmode(STDOUT);
   $| = 1;

   my $iter = make_iter(\*STDIN);
   while (my ($line) = $iter->()) {
      $line = "\e[1;91m" . $line . "\e[0m" if $line =~ /ERROR/i;
      print($line);
   }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

just insert a replacing pipe segment:

... | perl -pe 's/\r/\n/g' | ...

```
RUN.SH ${@} 2>&1 | perl -pe 's/\r/\n/g' | perl -M"Term::ANSIColor" -wnl -e '
m/ERROR/i and print "\e[1;91m", "$_", "\e[0m" 
or print;'
```

test:

```
ivr@linux-e8sg:~> echo -e 'a\nb\rc\n'
a
c

ivr@linux-e8sg:~> echo -e 'a\nb\rc\n'  | perl -pe 's/\r/\n/g'
a
b
c
```

Comment: There is one problem here though! When `JOB.SH` output is for instance a timer (which is why it does not print a new line), i'd have many many timers printed on new lines and not on the same line

Comment: That will still block until a newline is received.

Answer (score -4):

Oh boy, lots of great and wonder scripts that are not correct.

'$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR'  change this the default is '\n' you can change it to what you need on the fly in the  perl script itself.

You can read more at [perl special variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) use the web browser find and search "INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR"

Comment: Prey tell how to change it to "CR or LF"!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You can set `$/` to `\n` *or* `\r`, but not both.

Comment: you can set it to whatever you want "\n\n" "beer" etc.  Obvious lack of perl knowledge in the answers but whatever. Also I tested my own, I achieve the same results in very little code.

Comment: We don't know? Then educate us. Which value will cause `<>` to return if either CR or LF is encountered.

Comment: If you tested it, perhaps you should show the code you used.