# Any sequence of \r or \n as a line separator?

Tags: perl

I'm maintaining a Perl script (Perl 5.10 on Linux) which needs to process a file line-by-line while being as flexible as possible regarding line separator characters. Any sequence of newlines and/or carriage return characters should mark the end of a line. Blank lines in the file aren't significant. For example, all of these should yield two lines:

```
FOO\nBAR        FOO\rBAR
FOO\r\nBAR      FOO\n\rBAR
FOO\r\n\r\r\r\n\n\nBAR
```

It doesn't look like it's possible to get this behavior through `PerlIO` or by setting `$/`. The files aren't large, so I suppose I could just read the whole file into memory and then split it with a regular expression. Is there are more clever way to do this in Perl?

Comment: I think you're right, you can't do this just by setting `$/`. Unless it's huge, I'd slurp the file and then `split /[\r\n]+/, $blah`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the input record seperator to \n or \r when parsing lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156483/changing-the-input-record-seperator-to-n-or-r-when-parsing-lines)

Comment: Looks like you might be able to write a PerlIO layer to do it: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=813768

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just slurp the file and use `split`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Data::Dump;

my @data = (
    "FOO\nBAR",
    "FOO\rBAR",
    "FOO\r\nBAR",
    "FOO\n\rBAR",
    "FOO\r\n\r\r\r\n\n\nBAR",
);

for my $filedata (@data) {
    dd $filedata;

    open my $fh, "<", \"$filedata";
    local $/;
    for my $line (split /[\n\r]+/, <$fh>) {
        print "   $line\n";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
"FOO\nBAR"
   FOO
   BAR
"FOO\rBAR"
   FOO
   BAR
"FOO\r\nBAR"
   FOO
   BAR
"FOO\n\rBAR"
   FOO
   BAR
"FOO\r\n\r\r\r\n\n\nBAR"
   FOO
   BAR
```